# Is there a way to pull RTMPS live stream into a AWS Lambda using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, rtmp, live-streaming, rtmps

I am new here, and trying not to duplicate issues, so, I will try to be very specific.

I have a live RMTPS playback (with streamkey), somthing like this:

```
rtmps://{hostName}:443/live/{streamKey}
```

Using node.js in AWS Lambda, I would like to pull this stream, using that url, and be able manipulate/use this data.

At minimum I would like to create small segmented files out of this, mp3 files for instance to capture audio.

The Lambda would be a short lived instance, opened long enough to capture data for a specific amount of time. This is all proof of concept testing, but just curious on thoughts, packages, etc.

The main issues is actually pulling in that stream to use the data. Are there any packages, or anything that can run in the lambda environment, that can pull (read) the live rtmp?

When looking for ideas, I often saw things like Node Media Server, ffmpeg, rtmpdump. I am just not sure these able to be contained within the lambda?

Comment: RTMPS is designed for long-duration live streaming, whereas AWS Lambda is intended for short-term serverless functions. To convert RTMPS to HLS, you should consider using a solution like Kubernetes or a traditional web server to initiate and manage an FFmpeg process.

Comment: I'd agree with @Winlin, AWS Lambda will cost a fortune in this scenario and executing any binary from a Lambda is a nightmare. In any case you would need to fit in 5 minutes execution time (this could be extended to 15 minutes).

This is one of the reasons why we built the [Scramjet Transform Hub](https://github.com/scramjetorg/transform-hub) and the long-running lambda's that it can run. For your specific case take a look at [Ahead Server](https://github.com/signicode/ahead-server).